# Difference between const ethers and const { ethers }

Tags: javascript, hardhat

can anybody explain what is the difference between

```
const ethers = require("hardhat");
```

and

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

Comment: The first `const ethers = require("hardhat");` will require the entire hardhat library.  The second will require the ethers object that is exported by the hardhat library.  The second one is what you want.  If you need the entire library it should be `const hardhat = require("hardhat");`

Comment: @ruby_newbie Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what it means

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

If I`m now wrong it is same thing with

```
const helper = require("hardhat");
const ethers = helper.ethers;
```